# How to pass the Hadoop job queue name in jpmml cascading?

Tags: hadoop, cascading, pmml

I am trying to execute pmml model using cascading framework in jpmml cascading library provided in this project ***https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-cascading***

I have followed all the steps and was able to generate the **example-1.2-SNAPSHOT-job.jar** using mvn clean install command.

However when I am executing the same jar using the below command :

```
hadoop jar example-1.2-SNAPSHOT-job.jar /tmp/cascading/model.pmml file:///tmp/cascading/input.csv file:///tmp/cascading/output
```

I am getting below ***exceptions*** for not having the rights to submit the job on ***DEFAULT*** queue as default queue in our hadoop cluster is blocked for admin purpose only, normal user can not run the hadoop job without providing the queue name.

```
Exception:
16/01/06 04:41:37 ERROR ipc.FailoverRPC: FailoverProxy: Failing this Call: submitJob for error(RemoteException): org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): **User test cannot perform operation SUBMIT_JOB on queue default.**
 Please run "hadoop queue -showacls" command to find the queues you have access to .
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ACLsManager.checkAccess(ACLsManager.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ACLsManager.checkAccess(ACLsManager.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ACLsManager.checkAccess(ACLsManager.java:113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.submitJob(JobTracker.java:4524)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor17.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Server$WritableRpcInvoker.call(WritableRpcEngine.java:481)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:928)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2000)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1996)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1566)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1994)
```

I am not able to see where to provide the hadoop job queue in the repository.

Can anyone suggest how can I pass the hadoop job queue name?

Note:

> 1. I have tried to pass the property mapred.job.queue.name passing the queue name but still job is showing same error through command line
>      and in the code itself.
> 2. I have also tried to run the job using oozie shell action node and passing the queue name there in application workflow but I believe
>      that would be applicable for the oozie job only not the hadoop jobs
>      which gets executed through shell action node.

Comment: Do you have privileges to disable ACL checks in your cluster? One more question, which version of Hadoop are you using?

Comment: No I do not have privileges to diable ACL checks. it is hadoop 2.5.1

Comment: Posted an answer. Check

Comment: Hi Manjunath, i tried to change the queue name as you suggested but still getting the same exceptions. I think this is due to my point no.2 in Note in my question if you can check?

Comment: In Oozie you can set the queue for a MapReduce action with `mapreduce.job.queuename` property, and for any other action using a Launcher JAR (Java, Shell, Pig...) with `oozie.launcher.mapreduce.job.queuename`. **But** if Oozie starts a shell and the shell runs a "hadoop jar" command, you must again set explicitly the queue inside that command...

Comment: I totally agree with you and really appreciate to clear the air around the queue name. I do not know how to solve the same in Cascading framework, in particular hadoop cascading. before creating HadoopFlowConnector how can i set the job queue name same that we can set it using org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration and passing to the org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong settings. You should use the settings for **Hadoop 2.x**.

Following configuration properties (present in `mapred-site.xml`) control the submission to the job queues.

**Hadoop 1.x**

- `mapred.acls.enabled`: Whether ACL check should be enabled for checking user's privileges while doing a queue operation. It is set to `false` by default.
- `mapred.job.queue.name`: Queue to which a job is submitted. Default value is `default`.

**Hadoop 2.x**

- `mapreduce.cluster.acls.enabled`: Whether ACL check should be enabled for checking user's privileges while doing a queue operation. It is set to `false` by default.
- `mapreduce.job.queuename`: Queue to which a job is submitted. Default value is `default`.

You can set these values in different ways:

- Pass with `-D` option in the command line, while running a job. For e.g. you can pass it as `-Dmapreduce.job.queuename=default`.
- Set it in the `Driver` for the job (Hadoop 2.x):

  ```
  Configuration conf = new Configuration();
  conf.set("mapreduce.job.queuename", "default");
  Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "JobName");
  ```
- Set it in the `mapred-site.xml` file of the cluster.

Comment: It would be better if you can tell me how to set the hadoop job queue in Cascading framework. Please check this link for details : http://hortonworks.com/blog/cascading-hadoop-big-data-whatever/#comment-606913

Comment: @Nitin Mahesh, did you try passing `-D` option? For e.g. `hadoop jar -Dmapreduce.job.queuename=default ./build/libs/impatient.jar /data/rain.txt output/wc`

Comment: I believe that will be treated as GenericOptionParser in the jar file. Right now they are not treating the generic option parser thus command gives error while passing through generic options -D. This we can do in our normal hadoop jobs but how can i set the same in cascading framework for Hadoop is mystery for me.

Comment: One more clarification. Are you using the code from here:  http://hortonworks.com/blog/cascading-hadoop-big-data-whatever/#comment-606913, as is? Just want to confirm. I will have a look at it again and reply.

Comment: I am trying out the code from the link you gave me. I will update the answer, once I get something

Comment: Yes I am running the same code in my Map R cluster and I am getting that queue error. I have tried to set the queue in properties and as well as HadoopPlanner.copyJobConf(properties,conf);. I do not know where HadoopFlowConnector uses the property parameters to set the required configs before submitting hadoop step jobs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100010/discussion-between-nitin-mahesh-and-manjunath-ballur).